# TASKKILL and logical operators

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a script(working) which kills every task which is not equal with the windowtitle DEFENDINGSOFTWARE.
So it is:

```
Taskkill /FI “WINDOWTITLE ne DEFENDINGSOFTWARE*“ /F
```

How can I manage that he is also not killing the tasks which Name is “DEFENDINGSOFTWARE1”?

Comment: The `*`already does that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `*` already takes care of that.

```
Taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE ne DEFENDINGSOFTWARE*" /F
```

should kill

```
DEFENDINGSOTWARE
DEFENDINGSOTWARE1
DEFENDINGSOTWARE2
DEFENDINGSOTWARE - some text
```

As an example do from cmdline:

```
start "Test" pause
start "Test2" pause
```

You will have 2 titled `cmd` windows called

```
Test - pause
Test2 - pause
```

now run

```
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE EQ Test - pause"
```

which will only kill `Test - pause`

but running:

```
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE EQ Test*"
```

Kills all windows with a title starting with `Test`

Also, by running `taskkill /?` from cmdline you will see the filter switch help.

```
/FI   filter           Applies a filter to select a set of tasks.
                       Allows "*" to be used. ex. imagename eq acme*
```

with examples further down, where I selected the most relevant example, demonstrating this behaviour.

```
TASKKILL /F /FI "PID ge 1000" /FI "WINDOWTITLE ne untitle*"
```